# Administrator accounts cannot change their password

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, active-directory

I have the issue at one of my customers that some of their AD-accounts are not allowed to change their password via ctrl+alt+del.

The error they get: 'Permission denied'

What I found out about the specific accounts:

- The accounts are set 'cannotChangePassword:$false'
- In the security dialog of their AD-object, the principal 'self' is has no permission to change password
- It looks like it's only administrator accounts that are affected by this issue

What I already tried:

- Set 'cannotChangePassword' to $true and $false again -> This worked for > 2 hours
- Set principal 'self' the permission to change password on user in ADUC -> This worked for >2 hours
- Gave principal 'self' the permission to change password on object 'Domain\System\AdminSDHolder' -> No effect at all
- Passwords are ok in accordance to password policy settings (length, complexity, etc.)

Anyone of you with further ideas?

Comment: Check `gpresult` for a policy that prevents them from doing it. What of the things you tried was automatically reversed if any of them?

Comment: See the changes

Comment: Looked up the gpresult-report. Nothing suspicios here.

Comment: What time frame are you referring to by "some time"?

Comment: The title does not match your question.

Comment: True, fixed the typo